# Setting up new font in environment

Tags: xetex, environments

I'm defining a new environment to display some text in devanagari, but the text does not appear to be centered, despite defining `\centering` in the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=1.5]{Sanskrit 2003}

\newenvironment{myverse}
 {\myfont
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
 }


\begin{document}
\begin{myverse}
कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन  । \\
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूः मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥
\end{myverse}

Some text with translation.

\end{document}
```

Output: [image: Without centering]

If I use `\setmainfont`, the center occurs as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=1.5]{Sanskrit 2003}

\newenvironment{myverse}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}



\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=1.25]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{myverse}
कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन  । \\
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूः मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥
\end{myverse}

Some text with translation.

\end{document}
```

Output: [image: Output with centering]

How can I use `\newenvironment` to get centering to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment's definition is wrong. You should use in a way like below:

```
\newenvironment{myverse}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering\myfont}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
```

P.S. The correct  syntax is:

```
\newenvironment{name}[num]{before}{after}
```

where `name` is the name of the new environment, the `num` is the number of option(s), and `before` and `after` will be put before the text in the environment and afterward, respectively.